# Random_shuffle: Mostrar en pantalla los elementos barajados

Tags: c++

La explicación que viene en cplusplus es dificil para mi entendimiento y no logro comprender del todo como funciona esta función(random_shuffle). ¿Como mostrar el array barajado? ¿Algún fallo que recalcar?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int const MAX=10;

typedef int tArray[MAX];

int random (int i) { return rand()%i;}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    tArray miarray;
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        miarray[i]=i;
    }

    random_shuffle(miarray.begin(),miarray.end());
    random_shuffle(miarray.begin(),miarray.end(),random);

    cout << "La secuencia aleatoria es:";

    for()//mostrar los datos barajados
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pongo acá una versión donde trato de usar tu mismo código, lo más fielmente que puedo, pero con un estilo C++ actual. Fíjate en los comentarios y si tienes dudas que no puedes resolver con tu libro (porque necesitas un buen libro para empezar, ¿verdad?) puedes poner preguntas específicas para cada duda (me refiero a las dudas que no puedas resolver por tí mismo después de algún par de horas de estudio responsable, ¿verdad?)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include <random> // para default_random_engine()
                  // Generador de números pseudoaleatorios de baja calidad;
                  // probablemente el compilador use rand() internamente

using namespace std; // no es lo más aceptado, pero se usa mucho en ejemplos didácticos

int const MAX = 10;  // no se usan mayúsculas, y en particular "MAX" es un nombre peligroso

typedef int tArray[MAX]; // mejor que "typedef" es "using"


int main()
{

    tArray miarray;
    for (int i = 0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        miarray[i] = i;
    }

    int seed = static_cast<int>(time(NULL)); // (no uses cast de estilo C)

    shuffle(begin(miarray), end(miarray), std::default_random_engine(seed)); 

    cout << "La secuencia aleatoria es: ";

    for (const auto& i : miarray) { // "range based for loop" se usa muuuucho, acostúmbrate
        cout << i << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n'; // no uses endl a menos que sea _realmente_ necesario.

    return 0; // no es obligatorio, pero su ausencia puede poner nervioso a algún compañerito de banco.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Como mostrar el array barajado?

Pues muy fácil:

```
for (const auto &valor : miarray) // Mostrar los datos barajados.
{
    std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

> ¿Algún fallo que recalcar?

1. [`std::random_shuffle` ha sido marcada como deprecada a partir de C++14](https://www.meetingcpp.com/blog/items/stdrandom_shuffle-is-deprecated.html). Esta decisión se ha tomado porque la versión de `std::random_shuffle` que usa iteradores tiene una dependencia directa con [`std::rand` que se está dicutiendo deprecarlo también](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf), la función `std::rand` debe ser substituida por las funciones de la cabecera `<random>` ya que `std::rand` se considera dañino.
2. `miarray.begin()` y `miarray.end()` no compila. `miarray` es un alias de una formación de enteros (`int`) y como tal, no tiene funciones miembro.
3. [A `main` le falta el retorno](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139624/en-c-es-obligatorio-incluir-el-return-0-dentro-de-la-funci%C3%B3n-main).
4. [No se aconseja el uso de `using namespace std`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%C3%A9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica).
5. En C++ se aconseja que las definiciones (variables y símbolos) tengan el ámbito más pequeño posible, deberías mover el alias y la constante de tamaño al interior de `main`.
6. [Usar el operador de módulo (`%`) junto con `std::rand` para seleccionar números aleatorios es impreciso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/109264/2742).

Con las correcciones indicadas tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    constexpr int MAX = 10;
    using tArray = int[MAX];
    tArray miarray{};

    std::generate(std::begin(miarray), std::end(miarray), [i = 0]() mutable { return i++; });

    std::random_device dispositivo;
    std::mt19937 generador(dispositivo());

    std::shuffle(std::begin(miarray), std::end(miarray), generador); 

    for (const auto &v : miarray)
    {
        std::cout << valor << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Antes de nada, muchas gracias por responder de forma tan profesional. No obstante, esta algo lejos de mi entendimiento. Quedan claro los puntos 3,4,5,6.    Respecto a la 1, tenemos que random_shuffle es impreciso y necesita de srand pero eso implica mas lineas de código que utilizan shuffle y al no entenderlo bien, hace que se me complique mas.

Comment: Y por alguna razón que no entiendo, no logro que compile tu programa.

Comment: @Vendetta del punto 2 no mencionas nada, y es también importante. Si tienes dudas adicionales (y además ya has dado por resuelta esta pregunta) te animo a crear una pregunta adiciona sobre las dudas que te surjan. Respecto a que no compile el programa que puse de ejemplo, posiblemente tenga que ver con tu versión del compilador (pero no puedo adivinarlo sin ver los errores). Echa un vistazo a [este enlace](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yzh36emxe9UhigXu) que contiene una versión del programa funcionando.