# Poner "||" (or) en un while en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo C++. Estaba haciendo unos experimentos, entre ellos un programa donde hay 2 variables con valor de 100 y aletaroriamente se le resta un número a esas variables:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int vida = 100, evida = 100, rnd, rnd2;
    srand(time(NULL));  
    while(vida >= 0 || evida >= 0){
        rnd = 1+rand()%(11-1);
        cout<<vida<<"  "<<evida<<endl;
        rnd2 = 1+rand()%(3-1);
        if(rnd2 == 2){
            evida -= rnd;
        }
        else{
            vida -= rnd;
        }
    }
        return 0;
    }
```

La idea es que cuando la variable `vida` o `evida` lleguen a `0` se pare el `while`, pero en lugar de eso espera a que las 2 variables sean menores o iguales a `0`. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿No has pensado que en vez de un "o" `||` necesitas un "y" `&&`? Además, que sea un mayor estricto `>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Estoy aprendiendo C++.

En ese caso, permíteme darte la bienvenida `\ñ_ñ/` y darte algunos consejos:

- Las cabeceras [`<stdlib.h>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header) y [`<time.h>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono) son de [c](/questions/tagged/c) no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Estas cabeceras disponen de una versión adaptada a C++ que tiene el prefijo **`c`** y carece de extensión. Si realmente necesitas usar las cabeceras de C (que nunca será el caso) debes usar los equivalentes de C++ [`<cstdlib>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) y [`<ctime>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ctime). Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber por qué.
- No hay obligación de usar la cláusula `using namespace std;` pues es sólo es una ayuda a la escritura de código; si decides usar esta cláusula no lo hagas en el ámbito global, úsala en el ámbito más pequeño posible. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber por qué.
- Las funciones `rand()` y `srand()` pertenecen a las librerías de C, se desaconseja usar esas utilidades den C++ pues pueden no ser portables y pueden ofrecer resultados y rendimiento cuestionables, por ello [se está estudiando deprecarlo [image]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf). A partir del estándar C++11 existe una completa librería de [generación de números pseudoaleatorios [image]](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) que deberías usar en su lugar. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/109264/2742) para saber por qué.

> La idea es que cuando la variable `vida` o `evida` lleguen a `0` se pare el `while`, pero en lugar de eso espera a que las 2 variables sean menores o iguales a `0`.

Ese es el comportamiento esperado; en una condición unida por un or (`||`) la expresión será verdadera mientras alguna de las expresiones sea verdadera y en consecuencia será falsa cuando ambas expresiones lo sean:

```
|            tabla de la verdad OR           |
+-------------+-------------+----+-----------+
| expresión 1 | expresión 2 | || | resultado |
+-------------+-------------+----+-----------+
|    falso    |    falso    | || |   falso   |
|    falso    |  verdadero  | || | verdadero |
|  verdadero  |    falso    | || | verdadero |
|  verdadero  |  verdadero  | || | verdadero |
```

Tú lo que quieres es una condición and (`&&`), que será verdadera cuando todas las expresiones sea verdaderas y en consecuencia será falsa en los demás casos:

```
|           tabla de la verdad AND           |
+-------------+-------------+----+-----------+
| expresión 1 | expresión 2 | && | resultado |
+-------------+-------------+----+-----------+
|    falso    |    falso    | && |   falso   |
|    falso    |  verdadero  | && |   falso   |
|  verdadero  |    falso    | && |   falso   |
|  verdadero  |  verdadero  | && | verdadero |
```

Por lo tanto tu `while`, con and (`&&`):

```
while(vida >= 0 && evida >= 0)
```

Se podría leer como "*Mientras `vida` sea mayor o igual a `0` **Y** `evida` sea mayor o igual a `0`*".

Answer (score 4):

Tú quieres que cuando al menos vida o evida sean menores o iguales a cero salga del while, es decir:

```
vida <= 0 OR evida <= 0
```

Esa es la condición para que salga por lo que la condición para que se mantenga es la negación:

```
~(vida <= 0 OR evida <= 0)     =
~(vida <= 0) AND ~(evida <= 0) =
  vida > 0 AND evida > 0
```

Por lo que la condición correcta es:

```
vida > 0 && evida > 0
```

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main(){
    int vida = 100, evida = 100, rnd, rnd2;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis1(1, 11);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis2(1, 3);

    std::cout<<vida<<"  "<<evida<< "\n";
    while(vida > 0 && evida > 0){
        rnd = dis1(gen);
        rnd2 = dis2(gen);
        if(rnd2 == 2)
            evida -= rnd;
        else
            vida -= rnd;
        std::cout<<vida<<"  "<<evida<< "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
100  100
89  100
88  100
88  92
88  87
79  87
79  80
79  75
79  70
70  70
60  70
50  70
41  70
40  70
40  61
39  61
39  53
39  47
37  47
28  47
19  47
19  42
19  36
14  36
14  25
14  21
14  17
14  7
9  7
8  7
-1  7
```

Comment: Mi +1 por el uso de `std::uniform_int_distribution` :) aunque te aconsejo dejar un espacio en blanco entre la definición de tipo y el nombre de la instancia para facilitar la lectura y comprensión de la composición: `std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis2(1, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones, o poner un operador lógico **Y** (`&&`) en vez del **O** (`||`) y un mayor estricto (`>`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int vida = 100, evida = 100, rnd, rnd2;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (vida > 0 && evida > 0) {
        rnd = 1 + rand() % (11 - 1);
        std::cout << vida << "  " << evida << std::endl;
        rnd2 = 1 + rand() % (3 - 1);
        if (rnd2 == 2) {
            evida -= rnd;
        } else {
            vida -= rnd;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O cambiar el mayor o igual (`>=`) por un menor o igual (`<=`) todo negado (`!`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int vida = 100, evida = 100, rnd, rnd2;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (!(vida <= 0 || evida <= 0)) {
        rnd = 1 + rand() % (11 - 1);
        std::cout << vida << "  " << evida << std::endl;
        rnd2 = 1 + rand() % (3 - 1);
        if (rnd2 == 2) {
            evida -= rnd;
        } else {
            vida -= rnd;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```