# ¿Como hago para que me salgan 2 números diferentes llamando a la misma función? (rand) <time.h>

Tags: c++, funciones

El problema es el siguiente estoy desarrollando una función "baraja" con la librería de time.h y otra función que es la imagen de las cartas.
para así crear lo que seria la baraja de un juego que estoy programando.

A la hora de llamar a las funciones y ejecutar dicho código la función baraja me imprime siempre el mismo numero en el player 1 y el player 2. ¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto para que me imprima 2 números diferentes en el player 1 y el player 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
//FUNCIONES
void imagen_carta(int n);
void baraja (int *n);
int main(){
    int n, a, aux1, aux2;
    printf ("El player1 saco la carta:\n");
    baraja(&n);
    imagen_carta (n);
    aux1=n;
    printf ("El player2 saco la carta:\n");
    baraja(&n);
    imagen_carta (n);
    aux2=n;   
}
void imagen_carta(int n){
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++){      // dibujar la i-esima fila
        if (i==1||i==7){
            for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
            printf(".");
            printf("\n");
        }
        else{
            if(i==4){
                for (int b = 1; b <= 2; b++){
                printf(".");    
                if(b<2){
                    for(int j=1;j<=1 ;j++){
                    printf("   %d   ", n);
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    printf("\n");
                }

                }
            }
            else    
            {
                for (int b = 1; b <= 2; b++){
                printf(".");    
                if(b<2){
                    for(int j=1;j<=1 ;j++){
                    printf("    ");
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    printf("\n");
                }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void baraja (int *n) {   

    srand (time(NULL));

        *n = (rand() % 9) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La función `srand` establece la semilla del generador de [números pseudoaleatorios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_pseudoaleatorio), si usas la misma raíz obtendrás los mismos números.

Y eso es lo que sucede en tu código, la función `baraja`, en su primera instrucción establece la semilla al valor del retorno de `time`, si la llamada es muy seguida el valor será el mismo y reiniciarás la semilla obteniendo la misma serie de números pseudoaleatorios desde el principio.

Llama una sola vez a `srand` y se solucionará tu problema:

```
int main(){
    srand (time(NULL)); // <--- ¡¡AQUÍ!!
    int n, a, aux1, aux2;
    printf ("El player1 saco la carta:\n");
    baraja(&n);
    imagen_carta (n);
    aux1=n;
    printf ("El player2 saco la carta:\n");
    baraja(&n);
    imagen_carta (n);
    aux2=n;   
}

void baraja (int *n) {
        // srand (time(NULL)); ¡¡AQUÍ NO!!
        *n = (rand() % 9) + 1;
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Has etiquetado tu pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (de hecho has usado varias etiquetas de C++) pero salvo por la cláusula `using namespace std;` tu código es [c](/questions/tagged/c) puro. Para que fuese C++ deberías hacer las siguientes correcciones:

- No uses cabeceras de C: `<stdio.h>`, `<time.h>` y `<stdlib.h>` son cabeceras de C, tienen versiones portadas a C++ que son  `<cstdio>`, `<ctime>` y `<cstdlib>` que pueden ser usadas si fuese necesario, pero no es tu caso. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más del tema.
- En C++ se envían datos a la consola mediante el objeto `std::cout`, la función `printf` pertenece a la salida por consola de C, usa `std::cout`.
- Si tu idea es devolver un valor en una función, haz que lo devuelva en lugar de pasarle un puntero al valor. Si es un requerimiento pasar un valor para ser modificado dentro de la función, pasa una referencia no un puntero.
- Usa la cabecera `<random>` para generar números pseudoaleatorios, ofrece herramientas más flexibles y seguras que `rand`. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108985/2742) para saber más del tema.

Unos consejos adicionales, no directamente relacionados con traducir el código a C++:

- La función `main` debe devolver un valor. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139624/2742) para saber más del tema.
- Usa nombres autoexplicativos para tus variables, nombres como `n`, `a`, `aux1` y `aux2` no dan ninguna pista de para qué sirven dichas variables.
- Favorece el preincremento antes que el postincremento, lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber más del tema.

Con los consejos anteriores tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

struct Baraja
{
    int carta()
    {
        return distribucion(generador);
    }

    Baraja() :
        generador{dispositivo()},
        distribucion{1, 9}
    {}

private:
    std::random_device dispositivo;
    std::mt19937 generador;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion;
};

int main()
{
    Baraja baraja;

    std::cout << "El player 1 saco la carta: ";
    imagen_carta(baraja.carta());

    std::cout << "El player 2 saco la carta: ";
    imagen_carta(baraja.carta());

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZHBToQwEIbPzFNM1sNCshpXD2aB7EHjW5iQ2baaMdCSUkgM4dlxgN1114MHD5S2f/9v@k@Nqutb@cbxhq0qW20wZ9cEb6jaw8@eJ6ud7IBIrQr4TJ4@CXqI2AZU5APFCUSyjrwJrbeoWY7yoVXsbPxhrPGknU8yiAaAaPHHCabiOKu9mGrXcODOxcmwEe0S0283uBukihBqzx0FI/Ym6DRd7ldo07EyeIHJjgeqsN3tHp/wXOsktJbfna8KyVGcigUplu@vImQwZACdY41ckVCKJfQU3yZTI2aacm3APMfVy6TiaprbaVi/2bUwACZDRWzj2bT0AQ/zTwr8oryWWJf0ZTxusSHlsKSl2SmuJMDVTRbG3fEtkr9gD/@BHd/1XlKM4zc)</kbd>.